# JUnit test fails because of user home directory syntax

Tags: java, windows, junit

I am using Junit for my unit test, I want to test that my created file is created on the requested location, on this case the location is the tmp folder. My test fails because the user home directory got from 'tmpFile.getParent()' is not the same got from System.getProperty("user.home") :

```
tmpFile= File.createTempFile("tmpFile", ".tmp");
String actualFolder = tmpFile.getParent();/* the tmp file directory */  

String expectedFolder= System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
```

the Junit tests fails and in the consol, I got:

```
actualFolder = C:\Users\[USER_~1\]AppData\Local\Temp
expectedFolder = C:\Users\[user_000]AppData\Local\Temp>
```

How can I get the same syntax of the user directory as 'tmpFile.getParent()' ?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `new File(actualFolder).getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: A few notes: Unit tests should ideally not test the file system. But sometimes, you "need to", so maybe it makes sense here. If if does, you should probably make it file system agnostic. Right now, your test will fail unless you're on Windows, because of the backslashy paths. Also, I think the default temp folder is platform specific, so relying on it being under `"user.home"` may cause additional false positives (ie. test fails).

Answer (score 0):

The strings you are trying to compare are just a representation of the underlying file in the filesystem. As yole suggested, you should compare filehandles respectively their absolute or canonical path.